# Token not found in emailext plugin of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I'm trying to send an email with the [emailext](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin in jenkins. The relevant part of my declarative pipeline is:

```
post {
    always {
        emailext (
            to: 'bar@foo.com',
            subject: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: ${env.JOB_NAME} - build ${currentBuild.number}",
            body: "${FILE, path="$WORKSPACE/results/summary.txt"}"
        )
    }
}
```

This leads to the error:

```
WorkflowScript: 53: unexpected token: FILE @ line 53, column 26.
                    body: "${FILE, path="$WORKSPACE/results/summary.txt"}"
```

Why is the token `${FILE, path=""}` not working?

Answer (score 3):

It works with `'` instead of `"` for the `body` entry:

```
post {
    always {
        emailext (
            to: 'bar@foo.com',
            subject: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: ${env.JOB_NAME} - build ${currentBuild.number}",
            body: '${FILE, path="$WORKSPACE/results/summary.txt"}'
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you must use single quotes or groovy tries to replace ${XXXX} with its variables